# Jenkins does not abort on SVN error E175002

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline

I am calling `svn ls` from Jenkins on a SVN directory to get a list of paths that match a certain pattern (that I later process further).

Maybe not very nice, but this is currently how it works:

```
def proc = bat (returnStdout: true, script: '@svn ls https://path/to/my/repo/trunk -R --trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca --non-interactive | findstr /R "^[^_].*_src/$" | findstr /R "^FolderA ^FolderB" | findstr /V "_test"').trim()
```

### Problem

Sometimes due to connection issues the `svn ls` command fails and the Jenkins job aborts (which is perfectly ok because it is the expected behavior.
Sometimes however, it seems that only some folders / sub-folders are not accessible temporarily and I get an error *message*, but it seems not an error *signal* from the `svn ls`:

```
svn: E175002: Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on 'path/to/a/folder
```

This is a problem, because the pipeline does not abort, but continues and the content of `proc` only contains parts of the result, but not the full result.

Is there any way to detect this case where the error occurs? Please note, that not the occurrance of the E175002 error is my problem, but its detection.

Comment: You need to show us *full error received on Jenkins / client side* and show us *what's in your SVN server's logs*.

Comment: The issue only occurs randomly - maybe connection issues. The problem however is not that the issue occurs, the problem is how to detect it and why the svn return value is not != 0 in this case so that Jenkins can detect it